# Kendo Treeview Binding parent and children

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, treeview

I'm trying to follow this example here
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/treeview/ajax-binding

However, whenever I try to modify their code, I get an error saying

Error   2   'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ReadOnlyDataSourceBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.ReadOnlyDataSourceBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Users\Michael\Google Drive\Work\Companies\Clickable Community\dhvs\Clickable Community\Development\Portal\ClickableCommunity.Web\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml 34  ClickableCommunity.Web

Here is my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                        .Name("treeview")
                        // The property that specifies the text of the node
                        .DataTextField("Name")
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Model(model => model
                                // The property that uniquely identieis a node.
                                // The value of this property is the argument of the action method
                                .Id("Id")
                                // the boolean property that tells whether a node has children
                                .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                            )
                            .Read(read => read
                                // The action method which will return JSON
                                .Action("ReadCats", "Home")
                            )
                        )
                    )
```

and what I'm doing in my controller

```
public JsonResult ReadCats()
{
    var categories = _entityLogic.GetActiveCategories();
    var jsonResult = categories.Select(cat => new
            {
                Id = cat.Id,
                Name = cat.Name,
                HasChildren = categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategory == cat.Id).Any(),
                ParentId = cat.ParentCategory
            }).ToList();
    return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Basically, I have a table that stores and ID, name, and parentcategory (the id of the parent category) and I'm trying to bind a treeview to all my parent child nodes. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
So I still cannot get this. I keep getting the same error. I can't put @model namespace because it gives me an error saying it is a namespace but used like a type. Here is my entire code. Thanks,

```
@model ClickableCommunity.Web.Models.Public.HomeModel

@using ClickableCommunity.Core.Models.Data
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                            .Name("treeview")
                            // The property that specifies the text of the node
                            .DataTextField("Name")
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Model(model => model
                                    // The property that uniquely identieis a node.
                                    // The value of this property is the argument of the action method
                                    .Id("Id")
                                    // the boolean property that tells whether a node has children
                                    .HasChildren("HasChildren")
                                )
                                .Read(read => read
                                    // The action method which will return JSON
                                    .Action("ReadCats", "Home")
                                )
                            )
                        )

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.CategoryEntities)
{
    <li>
        @item.Name
    </li>

}
</ul>
```

And here is my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ClickableCommunity.Core.Contracts.Logging;
using ClickableCommunity.Core.Contracts.Logic;
using ClickableCommunity.Web.Models.Public;
namespace ClickableCommunity.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IEntityLogic _entityLogic;
        private readonly IGeogrpaphyLogic _geoLogic;
        private readonly IUserLogic _userLogic;

        public HomeController(ISystemLogger logger, IEntityLogic entityLogic, IUserLogic userLogic, IGeogrpaphyLogic geoLogic) : base(logger)
        {
            _entityLogic = entityLogic;
            _userLogic = userLogic;
            _geoLogic = geoLogic;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var catEnts = new List<HomeModel.CategoryEntitiesList>();

            var model = new HomeModel
            {
                AvailableCategories = _entityLogic.GetActiveCategories()
                , Entities = _entityLogic.GetActiveEntities()
                , States = _geoLogic.GetAllStates()
            };
            var tempCe = new HomeModel.CategoryEntitiesList();
            foreach (var i in model.AvailableCategories.Where(c => c.ParentCategory == null))
            {
                tempCe = new HomeModel.CategoryEntitiesList();
                tempCe.Name = i.Name;
                tempCe.ParentCategory = i.ParentCategory;
                tempCe.Id = i.Id;
                tempCe.HasChildren = model.AvailableCategories.Where(a => a.ParentCategory == i.Id).Any();
                catEnts.Add(tempCe);
            }
            model.CategoryEntities = catEnts;
            return View(model);

            //return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }


        public JsonResult GetChildTreeViewData(int? id)
        {
            var categories = _entityLogic.GetActiveCategories();
            if (id != null)
            {
                categories = categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategory == id);
            }
            var jsonResult = categories.Select(cat => new
                    {
                        Id = cat.Id,
                        Name = cat.Name,
                        HasChildren = categories.Where(c => c.ParentCategory == cat.Id).Any(),
                        ParentCategory = cat.ParentCategory
                    }).ToList();
            return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your View should define a Model in order for this to work

Add this line to the top of your View:

`@model categories` //or whatever namespace your Entity categoies are in

this should work fine!!

Comment: So If this tree was in my main layout file, where I don't use a model, how should I go about binding this? Should I create a partial form or something? Or can I bind it another way that you'd know of in my layout file?

Comment: yes, its always better to put the tree view in a seperate partial view and then let it interact with other views via ajax calls, thus you keep the tree view logic separated from others and easy to manage

Comment: Hey, I updated my original post with some more code. Do you think you could take a look and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!